# Woo-Commerce Product Query with Multiple Arguments

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to Query Woo-Commerce products based on the following

Featured 
Popular
Promotional
Free

I was working to show them in isotop so I have to get all products and give specifiq tag based on my query to make filter. I was confused if I can make 4 Query as I have 4 different arguments / parameter.

I made 4 different query and got result in 4 different array. But there have problems.

1. I had done 4 Queries and Save result on 4 array. So there same products containing. I have to filter all products and if same product in more than one category I have to input tag like features free . as Isotop works.
2. If I unique marge array it will not show products in multiple category. But same products can be in two categories or can be in all categories so it should add tag in duplicate product and clear duplicate products list so that in result there will be unique product with multi tag.

Any idea how to do that ?

Below is my code which providing all products.

```
<?php

                                foreach ($filter_attr as $item) {
                                    if ($item == 'featured') {
                                        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
                                        $tax_query = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
                                        $tax_query[] = array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                                            'field' => 'name',
                                            'terms' => 'featured',
                                            'operator' => 'IN',
                                        );

                                        $query_args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'product',
                                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                                            'posts_per_page' => '12',
                                            'orderby' => 'date',
                                            'order' => 'desc',
                                            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
                                            'tax_query' => $tax_query,
                                        );


                                        $loop = new WP_Query($query_args);

                                        if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                                            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                                                $featured_product = array(
                                                "type"=>$item,
                                                "product" => get_the_ID(),
                                                );

                                           endwhile;
                                        }  else {
                                            echo __('No products found');
                                        }
                                        wp_reset_postdata();

                                    }  elseif($item == 'popular'){

                                        $query_args = array(
                                            'post_type'           => 'product',
                                            'post_status'         => 'publish',
                                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                                            'posts_per_page'      => '12',
                                            'meta_key'            => 'total_sales',
                                            'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num'
                                        );

                                        $loop = new WP_Query($query_args);

                                        if ($loop->have_posts()) {

                                            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                                                $id=array();

                                                $popular_product = array(
                                                    "type"=>$item,
                                                    "product" => get_the_ID(),
                                                );

                                                print_r($popular_product);

                                            endwhile;
                                        }  else {
                                            echo __('No products found');
                                        }
                                        wp_reset_postdata();

                                    } elseif($item == 'promotional'){

                                        $query_args = array(
                                            'posts_per_page' => 12,
                                            'post_type' => 'product',
                                            'meta_key' => '_sale_price',
                                            'meta_value' => '0',
                                            'meta_compare' => '>='
                                        );

                                        $loop = new WP_Query($query_args);

                                        if ($loop->have_posts()) {

                                            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                                                $id=array();

                                                $promotional_product = array(
                                                    "type"=>$item,
                                                    "product" => get_the_ID(),
                                                );

                                               print_r($promotional_product);

                                            endwhile;
                                        }  else {
                                            echo __('No products found');
                                        }
                                        wp_reset_postdata();
                                    } elseif($item == 'freebies'){

                                        $query_args = array(
                                            'posts_per_page' => 12,
                                            'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
                                            'meta_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'key' => '_price',
                                                    'value' => 0,
                                                    'compare' => '<=',
                                                    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                                                )
                                            )
                                        );


                                        $loop = new WP_Query($query_args);

                                        if ($loop->have_posts()) {

                                            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                                                $id=array();

                                                $freebies_product = array(
                                                    "type"=>$item,
                                                    "product" => get_the_ID(),
                                                );

                                                print_r($freebies_product);

                                            endwhile;
                                        }  else {
                                            echo __('No products found');
                                        }
                                        wp_reset_postdata();
                                    }
                                }

                                ?>
```

Comment: Isotope is front-end filtering right? So why do you need to do 4 back-end queries?

Comment: Yes , Isotope is front-end filtering. You can check demo here https://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FilterableProductGrid . Its a html demo I am just making it dynamic with woo-commerce. So my question is 

1. Is there its a good way to make 4 queries in same file. Is there any other way to do that ? I hared about page load time increase for more than one queries.

2. How to short product from final result array where there are multiple product with same id in several group. I just need to add tag for multiple category product.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: "heard about page load time increase for more than one queries." This is true, and is one of the reasons I am asking you to explain why you need 4 queries. "multiple product with same id in several group" How are there multiple products with the same ID? Each product has a unique product ID.

Comment: If Product A is featured and popular, then Isotope would display it when filtering for either featured or popular. And it will show by default when viewing all. While featured doesn't have a category you can use with isotope, you can filter the `post_class` to add a featured status and use that since Isotope works off of CSS classes anyway.

Comment: Check the array from bellow link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayrfsvfurrjfgmf/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-20%20at%2010.26.24%20PM.png?dl=0
I got all products according to my query. 
1. Like I have a Product Name "iPhone" which is Featured and Also a Promotional and Popular product. So there One product in 3 Types. Now in my array I have One Product in 3 Category with its ID. So if I echo then it will repeat "iPhone" for 3 Times need to add a class in main div so if parent div like grid it will add featured popular promotional on that class.